# DXA dynamic type mapping

Tags: dxa, templating

I am trying to map a Component link field to a dynamic type Module and I am getting this error:

```
Unable to map field 'dynamic field' to property of type 'System.Object'.
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'Sdl.Web.Common.Models.ViewModel'.
```

Class:

```
public class aModel : EntityModel
{
    public List<dynamic> aField { get; set; }
}
```

Does DXA support dynamic type mapping? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

No, it doesn't; DXA uses Strongly Typed View Models. The supported View Model property types depend on the CM field type you are mapping to.

In case of a CM Component Link field, you can map it to a property of type `EntityModel` (so any kind of embedded Entity Model), but you can't make it more loosely typed than that.

Answer (score 2):

If you allow multiple schemas on a component link field, I would recommend think about the schema design up front so you can create a base view model class. Then you can avoid using dynamic type. It also means you will quite likely be able to reuse partial views.